# how to convert AVFrame to class

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

In order to facilitate the management of AVFrame resources，I want to convert AVFrame to class,but I  don't know how to write my copy constructor function and assignment function with default AVFrame(use av_frame_alloc() to alloc).

Comment: Maybe you should check the examples at https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, you can use  `av_frame_copy` to name a deep copy of the frame contents. Or you can use `av_frame_clone` to use ffmpegs reference counting features.